# How to do Named Entity Recognition in Tables?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

What are approaches to do Named Entity Recognition on Tables? I am referring to tables which have a column header and the corresponding information in the cells below the header, or the respective with line headers, not tables which contain full sentences. Since these NER lack the context of a sentence and are sort of determined by a header, the approaches I found (most depend on context) do not really work.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you don't have a lot of options, you're probably stuck with heuristics:

- Capital letters
- Regular expressions (e.g. for dates)
- List of predefined entities (e.g. from Wikipedia) stored in a dictionary